# How to change color result from Zoom Map to the Selected Row in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

i want to change color result from Zoom Map to the Selected Row. where we can change the color?

Comment: please be more specific, what is a zoom map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the selection color (globally) in the Setting/Options
dialog on the Canvas & legend tab

[image]

You probably have to change the project properties, too.

[image]

Comment: but when i change color, its not work. when I Zoom Map to the Selected Row color always yellow. How?

Comment: Then you have to change also the the project properties. I've added another picture to the answer.